# php: associate session cookie with logged in user

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a session array to store some data in

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
       if (!isset($_SESSION['drinks'])) {
        $_SESSION['drinks'] = array();
        }}
```

This applies only to logged in users but it is apparently associated with machines, not users. I have tested with 2 different users and the array holds the same values for both instead of being empty for the second user.
How can I associate a session array to each logged in user?

Comment: did you remember to delete all session data when logging out?

Comment: I only want to clear the userID session when logging out, not the drinks one.

Answer (score 1):

You associate the data to that specific userID

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
  if (!isset($_SESSION['userID']['drinks'])) {
    $_SESSION['userID']['drinks'] = array();
  }
  var_dump($_SESSION['userID']['drinks']);
}
```

Comment: +1, I had not considered keeping multiple users' session data around

Comment: If I eliminate duplicates with
        $drinks= array_unique($_SESSION['userID']['drinks']);
I get rray_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: That's because `$_SESSION['userID']['drinks']` is a String and should be Array. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Because I have defined $_SESSION['userID']['drinks'] = array(); like you suggested but it won't start as an array and I can not add elements to it

Comment: Silly me, you're right. Well that's weird, try `var_dump($_SESSION['userID']['drinks']);`, what do you get?

Comment: string(1) "A" 
I don't know where that A came from :)

Comment: I have the same code but I need it to be an array and I can't add elements to it: Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in..

Comment: There's not much to give. I had that session array and I was adding drinks to it $_SESSION['drinks'][] = $drink1, eliminating the duplicates with array_unique and outputting the content and I just realised that it's not tied to userID but to the machine and browser.

Comment: Ok but the thing is this: you're only creating that array if `!isset($_SESSION['drinks']`, I think that `$_SESSION['drinks']` exists and you're creating it. See my updated code and tellme what happens when you execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You could clear the session either just before login, or after logout:

`session_destroy();` to reset the entire session, or

`unset( $_SESSION['drinks'] );` for just that particular variable

Comment: +1, this is also a good option but I don't know if it suits the OP needs

Comment: Yeah but I want that array to still be available for the first user when he logs in again.